# How to check for an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, typeof

> **Real-world usage**
>
> typeof is very useful, but it's not as versatile as might be required. For example, `typeof([])` , is `'object'`, as well as `typeof(new Date())`, `typeof(/abc/)`, etc.
>
> For greater specificity in checking types, a `typeof` wrapper for usage in production-level code would be as follows (provided `obj` exists):

```
function type(obj, showFullClass) {

    // get toPrototypeString() of obj (handles all types)
    if (showFullClass && typeof obj === "object") {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj);
    }
    if (obj == null) { return (obj + '').toLowerCase(); } // implicit toString() conversion

    var deepType = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8,-1).toLowerCase();
    if (deepType === 'generatorfunction') { return 'function' }

    // Prevent overspecificity (for example, [object HTMLDivElement], etc).
    // Account for functionish Regexp (Android <=2.3), functionish <object> element (Chrome <=57, Firefox <=52), etc.
    // String.prototype.match is universally supported.

    return deepType.match(/^(array|bigint|date|error|function|generator|regexp|symbol)$/) ? deepType :
       (typeof obj === 'object' || typeof obj === 'function') ? 'object' : typeof obj;

 }
```

I have the above code snippet - referenced from the MDN webdocs -  to be most useful in answering the stated question.URL:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof . I must admit though that getting to fully understand the code is proving difficult - for instance, what is the 'showFullClass' argument in the function declaration and what do the following lines do? `var deepType = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8,-1).toLowerCase();` and
 `return deepType.match(/^(array|bigint|date|error|function|generator|regexp|symbol)$/) ? deepType :(typeof obj === 'object' || typeof obj === 'function') ? 'object' : typeof obj;`

Any help or assistance in code comprehension would be much appreciated!

Comment: Seems like `showFullClass` is supposed to be a boolean. It's only used once in a logical expression. It'd be good if there was examples of how to use this with their outputs.

Comment: You could use `obj.constructor.name`

Comment: I'm not sure how usefull the code is. JS has primitive types, object is just one of the primitives. The only type which needs some special handling is `null`, as `typeof` returns its type as "object". If you wanted to check the "type" or "class" of an object, `deepType` (as it's defined in the code) alone works fine for the purpose (without lower-casing), thought it's possible to fork the value since ES6.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys - all your input was very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever we  call `toString` on an object it returns `"[object type]"`, where `type` is the object type. So the goal of the `type(obj, showFullClass)` is to extract the `type` from 'toString' output string.

1.What is the 'showFullClass' argument in the function declaration?

showFullClass is a boolean type. So if pass true in it , It will just return the output of `toString` without any processing.
E.g.
`type(new Date(),true)` will return `[object Date]`

2. What `var deepType = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8,-1).toLowerCase();` do?

It extracts the `type` substring of `"[object type]"` string and then convert it into lowercase. Which starts at **8th index** of the string till the **second last index** of string. -1 means string extraction should end just before the last index(-1) of string.
E.g. If `obj` is date object `deepType` value will be `'date'`

3. What `return deepType.match(/^(array|bigint|date|error|function|generator|regexp|symbol)$/) ? deepType :(typeof obj === 'object' || typeof obj === 'function') ? 'object' : typeof obj;` do?

It checks if `deepType` matches to either "array" or "bigint" or "date" or "error" or "function" or "generator" or "regexp" or "symbol" then it returns `deepType`.

Otherwise if `typeof obj` is `'object'` or `'function'` return `'object'`.

Otherwise for primitive types like string,number,etc return its type.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain @Ankit